# iOS5 How to determine current view

Tags: ios, uiview, ios5

I want to determine programmatically the currently visible uiview. Is there a way to do this? I am intending to remove the current view but would like to confirm which uivew it is first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There could be many, many UIViews visible at any one time. So no, there is not a way to determine the currently visible view.

You can find out the current view controller using the current window's root view controller property, but you may then have more work to do depending on the structure of your app (eg, the root view controller could be a navigation controller or a tab bar controller).

I can't offer any more without some details of what you have already and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi jrturton: I solved my problem, I needed to have an empty uiview serve as my root controller so my other views could easily be removed and added. Thanks for offering to help.